# Get field from another json using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have two .json-files. 
The first is 1.json

```
{
    "id": "107709375",
    "type": "page",
    "title": "SomeTitle",
    "space": {
        "key": "BUSINT"
    },
    "version": {
        "number": 62
    }
}
```

And the second one logg.json:

```
{
    "id": "228204270",
    "type": "page",
    "status": "current",
    "title": "test-test",
    "version": {
        "when": "2016-11-23T16:54:18.313+07:00",
        "number": 17,
        "minorEdit": false
    },
    "extensions": {
        "position": "none"
    }
}
```

Can I paste version.number from logg.json into version.number 1.json using jq? I need something like that (it's absolutely wrong):

```
jq-win64 ".version.number 1.json" = ".version.number +1" logg.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `logg.json` as an argument file. You could then access its values to make changes to the other.

```
$ jq --argfile logg logg.json '.version.number = $logg.version.number + 1' 1.json
```

Of course you'll need to use double quotes to work in the Windows Command prompt.

```
> jq --argfile logg logg.json ".version.number = $logg.version.number + 1" 1.json
```

Although the documentation says to use `--slurpfile` instead, we only have a single object in the file so it would be totally appropriate to use `--argfile` instead.

Comment: It's probably not appropriate to use the deprecated `--argfile` option, since deprecated features tend to be removed in future versions.  Unfortunately, the `--slurpfile` alternative doesn't work exactly the same.